# error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token

Tags: c++

I'm a newb to C++ and I get the following error. I looked up similar topics, but didn't find the answer I need. Here is the script, the error is in line 23:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct rendeles {
    string nev;
    int mennyiseg;
};

struct teaceg {     
    string nev;
    int mennyiseg;
};

int szam; 

int hanyadikceg (string cegnev); 
{            //line 23
    for (int i=0;i<szam;i++)
    {
        if (cegek[i].nev==cegnev)
            {
                return i;
            }
    }
    return -1;
}

void osszesit()
{
    for (int i=0;i<szam;i++)   
    {

    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hány db rendelés lesz összesen?";
    cin >> szam;

    struct teaceg cegek [szam];
    struct rendeles rendelt [szam];     

    for (int i=0;i<szam;i++)          
    {
        cout << "A(z) " << i+1 <<". cég neve:";
        cin >> rendelt[i].nev;
        cout << "A(z) " << i+1 <<". rendelés mennyisége:";
        cin >> rendelt[i].mennyiseg;
    }

    cout << endl;
    for (int i=0;i<szam;i++) 
    {
        cout << "A(z) " << i+1 << ". rendelés: " << rendelt[i].nev << " " << rendelt[i].mennyiseg << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the foreign identifiers :-)

Thanks for all the help! Such a newbie mistake :-)

I still have a problem though: I want "cegek" and "rendelt" be dynamic arrays. So they can't be global variables. But in the function "hanyadikceg" I need to get their data. Could you show me pls how to pass the variables to the function properly? (what to write inside the "()" of the function "hanyadikceg") Thanks!

Comment: The semicolon turns the function header into a function prototype. The point of prototypes is that they don't have bodies.

Answer (score 8):

Remove the semicolon

```
int hanyadikceg (string cegnev); 
{
```

should become

```
int hanyadikceg (string cegnev)
{
```

Comment: ooh thx! such a newbie mistake :-)
I still have a problem though: I want "cegek" and "rendelt" be dynamic arrays. So they can't be global variables. But in the function "hanyadikceg" I need to get their data. Could you show me pls how to pass the variables to the function properly? (what to write inside the "()" of the function "hanyadikceg")
Thanks!

Comment: @user1257384 Start another question after doing some searching or reading.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon from the end of line 22.